# url doesn't change when moving to the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi~ I just wanna get some data from page.
I wanna navigate to the page programmatically.
But this page's url doesn't change when I move to the next page.
The site is http://goodauction.land.naver.com/auction/ca_list.php

I don't know why 
How can I solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you click the next page link, it posts data to server.
[image]

you can mimic the `post` use requests library.

```
import requests, bs4
payload = {
        'lawsup':0,
        'lesson':0,
        'next_biddate1':'',
        'next_biddate2':'',
        'state':91,
        'b_count1':0,
        'b_count2':0,
        'b_area1':'',
        'b_area2':'',
        'special':0,
        'e_area1':'',
        'e_area2':'',
        'si':11,
        'gu':0,
        'dong':0,
        'apt_no':0,
        'order':'',
        'start':60,
        'total_record_val':850,
        'detail_search':'',
        'detail_class':'',
        'recieveCode':'',}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0', 
          'Referer':'http://goodauction.land.naver.com/auction/ca_list.php'}
r = requests.post('http://goodauction.land.naver.com/auction/ax_list.php', data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

although there are many fileds, but the page is in the `start` field:
you can just post :

```
payload = {
        'state':91,
        'start':30,  # each page contains 30 record, next page +30 example: 0, 30, 60
        'total_record_val':850,}
```

Comment: really Thanks~~ I find the way how to scrap!!
you are great guy?? or girl?? ~~